# Angular.js: How to create controller in module?

Tags: module, angularjs, controls

I want define a controller when use module:

```
angular.module('todoList', [], function () {

}).controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    return function ($scope) {
        $scope.todos = [
            {
                text: "Hello"
            }, {
                text: "World"
            }
        ]
    }

})
```

then I want use the module and the ccontroller:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-app="todoList">  
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
            <span>{{todo.text}}</span>
        </li>>
</div>
```

but it render nothing, what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your controller is wrong, there is no need to have a return function.

```
angular.module('todoList', [], function () {

}).controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.todos = [
            {
                text: "Hello"
            }, {
                text: "World"
            }
        ]
})
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zZfj0qM1nQfxr40ulG62?p=preview)

Comment: How would I create an instance method on the myCtrl controller?

Comment: what do you mean by an instance method

Comment: I think my problem is more with ng-click no linking up somewhere. When I click a button I want to call a function on the controller rather than reading a property

Comment: @SomethingOn It will be better if you can ask a new question with your code shared

Comment: Just posted ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718741/why-is-ng-click-not-calling-my-controller-function

Answer (score 2):

### Official Docs:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

### Syntax:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myName1=angular.module("myName",[]);
myName1.controller("nameInfo",["$scope",function($scope){
$scope.name="Rajnish";
$scope.address="Delhi";
}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much different but this one works too.

```
angular.module('todoList', []).
    controller('myCtrl', 
      function ($scope){
       $scope.todos=[{text: "Hello"},{text: "World"}];
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this too by using JS strict mode-

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular.module('listProject', []);
})();

(function() {
'use strict';
angular.module('listProject').controller('MyController', ['$scope', 
  function($scope) {
    console.log("Hello From ListProject Module->My Controller"):

   }

])

})();
```