# Why is ng-click not calling my controller function?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following service for getting an access token from my REST API:

```
var myServices = angular.module('myServices ', ['ngResource']);

myServices .factory('Auth', ['$resource',
  function($resource){    
    return $resource('http://192.168.0.17:3333/login', {}, {
      login: {method:'POST', params: { username: 'user1', password: 'abc123' }, isArray:false}
    });
  }
]);
```

And I have the following controller defined:

```
    var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers ', []);

        myControllers.controller('AuthCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', function($scope, Auth) {
          $scope.login = function() {
              console.log('Login');
              Auth.login();
            };
        }]);
```

My login form is as follows:

```
<form ng-controller="AuthCtrl">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"  ng-model="userpassword" />
    <button type="submit" ng-click="login();">Login</button>
</form>
```

When I click the "Login" button it doesn't call the login() function of the AuthCtrl and I can't figure out why :s

Comment: where did you use ngApp

Comment: The login form is a partial but ng-app is defined as "myApp" on the <html> tag...

Comment: is there any error in your browser console

Comment: and please share the ngApp declaration

Comment: I think you just solved it for me though...the AngularJS tutorial is a big confusing when they use the above syntax because they are defining multiple modules. I added a div around my form with ng-app="myControllers" and it worked

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZW3LV/1/

Comment: the ngApp should contain all the modules used by it...

Comment: If you add `$scope.foo = 'bar';` to your controller, then `{{foo}}` in your form, do you see "bar"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem ended up being an np-app derivative. More specifically a missing derivative. I had the usual

```
<html np-app="myApp">
...
</html>
```

But when organizing my code and writing it the way that Google recommends, I realized that I had actually created another app. With this code for myControllers, which is an ill named module:

```
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers ', []);
```

The login form is in a partial so I added a div around the form with the myControllers app directive:

```
<div ng-app="myControllers">
<form ng-controller="AuthCtrl">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"  ng-model="userpassword" />
    <button type="submit" ng-click="login();">Login</button>
</form>
</div>
```

AngularJS is written to be very VERY modular. You can have multiple apps, your controllers should only wrap the DOM elements that it needs to so if something isn't working double-check that you've added the necessary derivatives to the DOM ;)

Comment: Did you mean to type `np-app` and not `ng-app`? Please accept your answer to close the question.

Answer (score 6):

I think that you are going to be upset with yourself. I was able to fix this by removing the space after the myControllers declarations. Check this:

```
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers**YOU HAD A SPACE HERE**', []);
```

I change it to the following, and it worked. It looks like you are going to have the same issue with your service.

```
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []); //no space after the myControllers
```

[SEE MY CODE HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/ql7XNRwPyoc8U4bq3WKE?p=preview)

Comment: Hahah thanks @aaronfrost, but that wasn't actually the problem it was an incorrect ng-app declaration...I'll post my answer as soon as I can.

Comment: That could be true. I added an app declaration in the ng-app="myControllers" in the html tag. So, it could have been either one of those, I suppose. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias when defining Controller in your angular configuration. For example:
NOTE: I'm using TypeScript here

Just take note of the Controller, it has an alias of homeCtrl.

```
module MongoAngular {

var app = angular.module('mongoAngular', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute','restangular']);

app.config([
    '$routeProvider', ($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) => {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/Home', {
                templateUrl: '/PartialViews/Home/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController as homeCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Home' });
    }])
    .config(['RestangularProvider', (restangularProvider: restangular.IProvider) => {
    restangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/api');
}]);
}
```

And here's the way to use it...

```
ng-click="homeCtrl.addCustomer(customer)"
```

Try it.. It might work for you as it worked for me... ;)